# Elegant way to strip spaces at once across dataframe than individual columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe `hash_file` and it has two columns `VARIABLE` and `concept_id`.

```
hash_file = pd.DataFrame({'VARIABLE':['Tes ','Exam ','Evaluation '],'concept_id': [1,2,3]})
```

To strip spaces in the values of these two columns, I use the below code

```
hash_file['VARIABLE']=hash_file['VARIABLE'].astype(str).str.strip()
hash_file['concept_id']=hash_file['concept_id'].astype(str).str.strip()
```

Though this works fine, I can't use this approach because my real dataframe has more than 150 columns.

Is there anyway to strip spaces from all the column and its values at once? Like in one line?

**update screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Both the answers given below works fine. both are equally good. However @anky_91 is a bit good in terms of performance, I mark his answer as solution

Comment: hmmm, one thing - do you need finally all strings columns?

Comment: Yes, the solution by @jezrael is more generalized :)

Comment: yes, it depends what OP need...

Comment: Okay. cool. When I run in sample dataframe given above, the time was less for stack(), untack() approach. Pasting the screenshot

Comment: @jezrael - updated the answer to your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only strings columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) per columns with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
cols = hash_file.select_dtypes(object).columns
hash_file[cols] = hash_file[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

If no missing values in strings:

```
cols = hash_file.select_dtypes(object).columns
hash_file[cols] = hash_file[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

**Performance**:

```
[9000 rows x 150 columns] (50% strings columns)
```

---

```
hash_file = pd.DataFrame({'VARIABLE':['Tes ','Exam ','Evaluation '],'concept_id': [1,2,3]})
hash_file = pd.concat([hash_file] * 3000, ignore_index=True)
hash_file = pd.concat([hash_file] * 75, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

---

```
In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = hash_file.select_dtypes(object).columns
    ...: hash_file[cols] = hash_file[cols].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    ...: 
338 ms ± 14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = hash_file.select_dtypes(object).columns
    ...: hash_file[cols] = hash_file[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
    ...: 
368 ms ± 7.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [16]: %%timeit
    ...: cols = hash_file.select_dtypes(object).columns
    ...: hash_file[cols] = hash_file[cols].stack().str.strip().unstack()
    ...: 
818 ms ± 17.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [17]: %%timeit
    ...: hash_file.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    ...: 
1.09 s ± 21.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: hash_file.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
    ...: 
1.2 s ± 32.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: hash_file.astype(str).stack().str.strip().unstack()
    ...: 
2 s ± 25.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

`stack()` , `strip()` , `unstack()`:

```
final=hash_file.astype(str).stack().str.strip().unstack()
```

Or:
`applymap()`:

```
final=hash_file.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Performance on 9000 similar rows, surprised to see applymap performs quite better:

[image]

Comment: It works. mark as solution after time limit is over

Comment: In lambda function, `x` is each column?

Comment: @SSMK no, applymap applies to each element, for each column you can do : `hash_file.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())` , but this will be slower IMO than `stack()` and `unstack()`

Comment: Won't applymap on each value will be slower? I didn't time it. But just asking. let's I have 10 columns and each column has 100 records, so we have 10*100 elements. `applymap` runs on all this 1000 elements. Am I right? Wouldn't it be slower than just applying on 10 columns?

Comment: @anky_91 - Maybe answer should be changed, because all strings columns is not good idea, or?

Comment: @jezrael in general correct, you ave got it covered, here OP shows all string by `astype` :)

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, if need OP strings all columns finally, your solution is good, but obviously it is not required

Comment: @jezrael and @anky_91 anky - I am learning Python. Your discussion helped understand the nuances which should be considered while marking an answer as solution. Yes, its my bad that I had `.astype(str)` for a `concept_id` column which is not required as Jezrael said. However I thank you both and happy learning

Comment: @jezrael I am equally surprised, applymap performs better